# How to search for content in all my Mathematica files, or in the opened ones?

Tags: searching

I have one file where I used the package 'ReactionKinetics' but I forgot where. Does Mathematica allow for searches in all  Mathematica files, or in the opened ones, like certain editors (Winedt, ...) do?

Comment: To search for a file in Windows you would not use MMA but e.g. an application like "Everithing".

Comment: Look at [`TextSearch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextSearch.html).

Comment: Yes!  Both work :)

Comment: And never use Windows text search over directories of .nb files. Seems to crash the system regularly.